# Рандомизировать массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, javascript-faq

Существует массив по тупому заполенный пушем

`iq_id.push('.$Res['question_id'].');`

`имеет вид [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`

необходимо его перемешать (рандомизировать) и задать ключ. т.е что бы он стал вида

`[1=>'3', 2=>'1',3=>'5',4=>'2'... и тд`

к несчастью, мозг не догадывается как это сделать.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array/2450976#2450976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function randomShuffle(arr) {
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return Math.random() - 0.5
    });

    var obj = {}, i = 1;
    while(arr[i]) {obj[i] = arr[i++]};
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для тасования можно использовать версию [алгоритма Фишера-Йетса](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%E2%80%93%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC), а затем к результату применить map:

```
function shuffle(arr) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    { 
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tmp =  arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }
    return arr.map(function (item, index) { 
                       return { key : index + 1, value : item };   
                   });
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется автор имел ввиду, что рандомизированный массив нужно преобразовать в object.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел у себя на диске. Писал для себя, поэтому возможно не лучший вариант.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getRandomArray(len) {
    len = len || 20;
    for (var i = 0, arr = []; i < len; i++) {
        arr.push(getRandomInt(0, 100));
    }
    return arr;
}
```