# Рандомная загрузка объектов JSON

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, frontend

Есть файл json с данными по карточкам товаров. Надо, чтобы контент загружался c рандомной сортировкой (перезагрузка страницы должна вызывать изменение порядка карточек внутри блока). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: А что именно у вас не получается? Отобразить карточки? Произвести рандомную сортировку массива? Получить данные из json?

Comment: Выводятся карточки, с данными из json. но по порядку, а надо, чтобы рандомно, при каждой перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Покажите ваш код. По вопросом есть кнопка Править.

Answer (score 0):

По сути, это просто случайное перемешивание массива.

Ответ частично взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/305407/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)

```js
let data = ['dog',2,'apple',false,33,'house',true,8,9,'green']

function randomShuffle(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return Math.random() - 0.5
    });
}

console.log(randomShuffle(data))
```